# Eye diagram measurement of a CLK using an Oscilliscope

Tags: clock, oscilloscope, diagram

I'm still a junior engineer and wondering how to perform eye diagram measurement of a CLK using an Oscilliscope? 
My second question: Is the eye diagrams just using to measure CLKs, or one may also measure Data using eye diagram?
My third question: what are the benifits in the verification when using eye diagrams instead of normal timing diagrams?

Comment: http://www.edn.com/design/test-and-measurement/4389368/Eye-Diagram-Basics-Reading-and-applying-eye-diagrams

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eye diagrams are not really useful when looking at a clock signal because to make any sense of it requires triggering on the rising or falling edge. Once that is accomplished it won't look like an eye diagram: -

[image]

It will look like this: -

[image]

Now, to my mind, that is not an eye diagram.

> My second question: Is the eye diagrams just using to measure CLKs, or
>   one may also measure Data using eye diagram?

Not useful for clocks because they are technically not eye diagrams BUT very useful for continuous synchronous data. If the data is asynchronous and sent in short burts then it's not useful because the eye diagram will "fail" in between burts. If looking at asynchronous data then use a storage scope and capture several bytes and examine as if examining the clock signal mentioned earlier. Maybe like this: -

[image]

Answer (score 1):

An eye diagram is not useful to observe a clock signal because the clock is periodic.  It is most useful for observing data signals because it allows the results of many data bits to be displayed on one diagram.  It is very useful in showing how different bit patterns affect the ability of a data receiver to correctly decode 1's and 0's. Intersymbol interference can occur in digital data transmission systems when certain bit patterns are sent.  The eye diagram is the easiest way to observe these effects. An open eye means that the receiver can easily detect a 1 versus a 0.  As the eye closes, the threshold between 1's and 0's is decreasing and it is harder to differentiate 1's from 0's.  When this happens, the error rate of the system increases. This is only a brief introduction to the use of eye diagrams.

Comment: do you have info on how to measure eye diagram instead of normal?